# AJAX not rendering in JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

Sorry for my english.

Method `delete` from `TestMB`:

```
public String delete(Post post) {
    getDao().delete(post);
    return "success";
}
```

test.xhtml :

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <ui:repeat value="#{TestMB.entityList}" var="entityList">
        <p>
            #{entityList.name}

            <h:commandLink action="#{TestMB.delete(entityList)}">
                del
                <f:ajax render=":form1"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </p>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

Page does not refresh when I clicked the link "del". If I click again, the page will refresh. Why?

if I use new method `delete` from `TestMB`:

```
private String txt1="test";

public String delete() {

    try{
        Thread.sleep(Long.valueOf("10000"));
    }catch(Exception ex){}

    txt1="";

    return "";
}
```

And new `test.xhtml`:

```
<h:form id="form1">

    #{testMB.txt1}

    <h:commandLink action="#{testMB.delete}">
        del
        <f:ajax render=":form1"/>
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

I click the link "del" and the page refresh in 10 seconds.

Why not work in the first case?

Comment: After the link is clicked, the page should be navigated to `success.xhtml` (with whatever the suffix is - implicit navigation as it appears). `TestMB` in the first case looks wonky. It should begin with a small case letter. Is that action method invoked properly, when you click the link in the first case? If it is invoked properly then, it should navigate to the target page for sure unless there are some errors/exceptions in the middle.

Comment: Metod `delete` is work in the first case, it removes entries from db. I do not see errors in the glassfish log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

```
public List<Entity> getEntityList() {

    //if(entityList == null){
        entityList=getDao().findAll(getPageRequest());
    //}

    return entityList;
}
```

Comment: What is this? You nowhere mentioned in the question about this unknown thing.

Comment: Why? I wrote `<ui:repeat value="#{TestMB.entityList}" var="entityList">`.

Comment: Well, it is actually difficult to imagine how did you solve the actual problem - comparing the question contents with the given answer here, no-one could imagine that writing this kind of code could solve that "*page refresh*" problem. As a side note, writing business logic in a getter method is a bad practice. Getter methods are essentially invoked several times. As a consequence, that DAO method is being executed several times causing any SQL statement(s), if any in the `findAll()` DAO method to be executed several times on the database which is naturally a very expensive operation.